# How to perform SQL injection in PHP while inputting the data in input box?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

How to perform **`SQL Injection`** in the context of **`Insert query`** or **`Select query`**? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to allow SQL injections?

Comment: Well combine this, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php, with the answer below and you will be able to execute that query. You also can say good bye to your DB with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, don't use **mysql_**, use **mysqli_**.

Second, that's because you can't put two queries inside the `mysql_query()`. Otherwise they would have named it `mysql_queries()`

Just make two seperate queries. Here's the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

Here is a basic example from the manual on its usage:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

/* Create table doesn't return a resultset */
if ($mysqli->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City") === TRUE) {
    printf("Table myCity successfully created.\n");
}

/* Select queries return a resultset */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name FROM City LIMIT 10")) {
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

/* If we have to retrieve large amount of data we use MYSQLI_USE_RESULT */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM City", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {

    /* Note, that we can't execute any functions which interact with the
       server until result set was closed. All calls will return an
       'out of sync' error */
    if (!$mysqli->query("SET @a:='this will not work'")) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }
    $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: I edited the answer in order to use an English reference http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php